# How to set the `-ferror-limit` when using Fastlane

Tags: ios, xcodebuild, fastlane

I have an iOS project that uses a few CocoaPods that throw a lot of warnings when compiled.

In my Podfile I have the `inhibit_all_warnings!` that prevent the warnings from showing up on Xcode build.

When I use Fastlane it throws the `fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]` error.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17925872/1732725) answer tells me that adding the `-ferror-limit=0` argument make it ignore the warnings and continue compiling.

I tried adding `xcargs: '-ferror-limit=0'` to the ipa action call in Fastfile, but it didn't work.

How can I make the Fastlane's ipa action to ignore the warnings and continue compiling?

Comment: Did you try to set "Other Warning Flags" to '-w', or did you set "Inhibit All Warnings" to 'Yes' in Pods project? Both options can be found in 'Build Settings'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since fastlane changed from `shenzhen` to `gym` this parameter doesn't seem necessary anymore.