# Xcode -How to Add Compiler Flags in Xcode 14.1

Tags: xcode

I need to add `-ferror-limit=0` as a [compiler flag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17925872/4833705). I'm using Xcode 14.1 but posts that show how to actually do it are older versions of Xcode. For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7932898/4833705)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Click on your project in the project navigator.
- Select your target.
- Go to the "Build Settings" tab.
- In the filter field in the upper right (search field), enter "c flags".
- (You may need to set the selection in the upper left "Basic, Customized, All" to "All".)
- In the settings list, you should now find the "Other C flags" entry.
- Click into the value field to the right of "Other C flags", enter your value and press Enter.
- If the "Combined, Level" selection in the upper left is set to "Level", you probably want to set this in the second column which has the name of your target.

Answer (score 0):

- Open your Xcode project and select the target for which you want to add the compiler flags.
- Go to the "Build Settings" tab and search for "Other C Flags" or "Other Swift Flags" depending on the language you are using.
- Double-click on the value for "Other C Flags" or "Other Swift Flags" to open the edit field.
- Add your compiler flags, separated by spaces, in the edit field.
- Press "Enter" or click "Done" to save your changes.