# There is the right place to add -U__STRICT_ANSI__ to XCode build settings?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, xcode4.2, compiler-flags

I try to add `-U__STRICT_ANSI__` to my project build settings in XCode. But if I add it as "preprocessor macros" the commandline result is `-DU__STRICT_ANSI__`. 
XCode adds automatically "D". 
If I add it e.g. to `OTHER_CPLUSPLUSFLAGS` -> XCode ignores this flag.

Do anybody know there to add a "undef"-preprocessor flag ( e.g. `__STRICT_ANSI__`) in XCode 4.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently running XCode 5.0.2, but I believe the answer will be similar...

1. Open up your .xcodeproj file.
2. Click on "Build Settings".
3. Scroll to "Apple LLVM 5.0 - Custom Compiler Flags". (This step will probably be different for XCode 4.2. The section may also be called "Apple LLVM compiler 3.0 - Language".)
4. Click on "Other C Flags", and hit the return key.
5. Type `-U__STRICT_ANSI__` and hit return again.

These steps should cause XCode to set the `-U__STRICT_ANSI__` compiler flag. There's a nice illustration in this other Stack Overflow post: [Xcode Project-Wide compiler flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7932834/xcode-project-wide-compiler-flag)

Comment: But there is only a point CXX FLAGS and that i have already tried. I think there is something other not correct - i have added the flag to the warning flags and from there it works now. Thanks for spend your time!

If i have found the problem, i will post it!